# ValueError: time data does not match the given format

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '12FEB20210017', 1: '18AUG20210019'}})

df_time['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time.DOB,format='%d%b%Y%H:%M:%S')
```

> ValueError: time data '12FEB20210017' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S' (match)

I don't understand the problem with the format

Comment: Even if i add '00' at the end gives the same error.

Comment: You don't have colons in your input strings, but you are telling pandas that your input string has colons in the %H:%M:%S fields. Try: `df_time.DOB,format='%d%b%Y%H%M%S'`

Comment: Removing the colons fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format needed a slight change.

```
   import pandas as pd
   df_time = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '12FEB20210017', 1: '18AUG20210019'}})
   #df_time['DOB'] = df_time['DOB'].str.lower()
   df_time['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time.DOB,format='%d%b%Y%H%M')
```

Comment: This is the outcome I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: Check if you really have seconds in your data. I think you only have hours and minutes. if this is 12FEB20210017 0th hour and 17th minute use my answer. (you don't need %S at the end).

Comment: Yes I don't have seconds in my data

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comments ,errror message is clear and your data format should be like this :

```
import pandas as pd

df_time = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '12FEB20210017', 1: '18AUG20210019'}})
df_time['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df_time.DOB,format='%d%b%Y%H%M%S')

df_time
```

output:

```
>
                  DOB
0 2021-02-12 00:01:07
1 2021-08-18 00:01:09
```